# Beyond Homothetic and Killing vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, affine-geometry, general-relativity

I recently read that if a vector field satisfies $$L_v g_{ij}=a g_{ij}$$ then if $a=0$ or positive then v is Killing or Homothetic. What happens when a is negative?. Where $L_v$ is the Lie derivative and $g_{ij}$ is the metric.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, such a vector field is homothetic so long as $a$ is a constant.